# How can I edit a file in Linux and add line breaks?

Tags: linux

this is input

```
R0001 893573.56035613.416.60002 893580.06035624.316.80003 893586.56035635.116.91
R0004 893593.06035646.017.00005 893599.46035656.917.00006 893605.96035667.817.01
```

I want this

```
R0001 893573.56035613.416.6
0002 893580.06035624.316.8
0003 893586.56035635.116.91
R0004 893593.06035646.017.0
0005 893599.46035656.917.0
0006 893605.96035667.817.01
```

i use linux centos 5.4

Comment: What's the rule? How to determine where the line break should be inserted? What tools are you using? What have you tried? Please expand the question with as much relevant info as you can (using the [edit] link).

Comment: so you want alternating lines of 27 and 26 character lengths? Please edit your question to make your requirement explcit.

Comment: Are you asking how to launch a text editor to add line breaks?  Are you asking how to add line breaks programmatically?  Using what language?

Comment: i wanna add line break after column 27 and 53 and i wanna make it with Linux commands is that possible

Comment: Next time please edit your question and give all the relevant infos there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in file named "file":

```
sed -i 's/^\(.\{27\}\)\(.\{26\}\)\(.*\)/\1\n\2\n\3/g' file
```

sed is a very powerful tool for text processing, although not the easiest to use (but very easy when you want to make an example like this).
Here is the magic:

"-i" is a flag for "do this stuff for me"
in single quotes there is an instruction which consists four parts separated by slashes:
1. command: "s" - substitute
2. pattern: what do want to change
3. expected result: how do you want it to look like
4. range: "g" - global

The pattern is

```
\(.\{27\}\)\(.\{26\}\)\(.*\)
```

which means "make a group of first 27 characters in a line, then make another group of next 26 characters, and then make a first group of all the remaining character in the line".

The expected result is

```
\1\n\2\n\3
```

which means "paste group one, paste new line, paste group two, paste new line, paste group three".

To make it more clear you can put it in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
COLUMN1=27
COLUMN2=26
FILENAME="file"     
sed -i "s/^\(.\{$COLUMN1\}\)\(.\{$COLUMN2\}\)\(.*\)/\1\n\2\n\3/g" file
exit 0
```

To make a script open any file editor (I use vim, other options are emacs, nano, kwrite, kate, geany, gedit... I can go on like that all day) and paste the code above. Save it, close the editor and issue

```
chmod +x script
```

to be able to execute it. You call scripts by

```
./script
```

Now you can provide arguments to your script, check if "file" exists, add more breaking points... but that is another story.

And then you can use a different tool, like awk (which I strongly recommend, but I usually use regex when I write in vim and sed is more like vim than awk, so I feel more comfortable with it).

More reading:

http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/Find_and%20Replace_with_Sed.html

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~dholland/computers/awk.html

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

If your input is defined in **in.txt** a possible solution could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open ( FILE, "<", "in.txt") or die $!;
while (my $line = <FILE>) {

my $tmp = join("\n", unpack("(A53)*", $line));
my $message = join("\n", unpack("(A27)*", $tmp));
print "$message\n";

}
close(FILE);
```

I don't think this is the best solution because it's not working for long lines. But I gave it a try in Perl.